# Different page delivered based on variable

Tags: javascript, html

I had this reletivly simple html/javascript document working with 2 possible outcomes (using just > or <), and I have attempted to scale it to 8 options.

```
     <!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Fielder's Choice Spinner</title>

    <meta name="description" content="Instore spinner for FC">
    <meta name="author" content="Matthew Davis">

    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!--ill just leave this here-->

    <script language="JavaScript">
        var response = (function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(1);
  max = Math.floor(1000);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; //The maximum is inclusive and the minimum is inclusive 
})();

        document.write(response)

        function script() {
            if (response == 1000) {
                window.location.replace("freeorder.html")
            } 
            if (999 >= response >= 950){
                window.location.replace("15offorder/15offorder.html")
            }
            if (949 >= response >= 849){
                window.location.replace("20offnext.html")
            }
            if (848 >= response >= 698){
                window.location.replace("keychain.html")
            }
            if (697 >= response >= 497){
                window.location.replace("freebaseball.html")
            }
            if (496 >= response >= 396){
                window.location.replace("nospin1.html")
            }
            if (395 >= response >= 295){
                window.location.replace("nospin2.html")
            }
            if (294 >= response >= 1){
                window.location.replace("stamp.html")
            }
        }
        </script>
</head>

<body>

    <button id="link">Link</button>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('link').onclick = function () {
           script();
    };
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

However now the button only redirects when the criteria for *stamp.html* are achieved and the button is pressed. All other results the button does nothing. There are no errors in the browsers developer console. Is this an issue with the 'if' statements, or something else?

Cheers, Matt

Comment: What have you tried to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
 294 >= response >= 1
```

it evaluates to:

```
 (294 >= response) >= 1
```

thus:

```
resp = 10
(294 >= 10) == true
true >= 1 // this evaluates to true
```

But this doesn't work for your other if statements:

```
999 >= response >= 950

response = 960
999 >= 960 === true 
true >= 950 === false
```

and thus never fall into this if statement.

You need to make 2 explicit checks:

```
if (999 >= response && response >= 950)
```